# Android alarm manager v/s Phone setting

Tags: android

I am creating an app which as settings for alarm. My alarm rings when it sets.
Now I want to know if my mobile is in silent mode and i have set alarm on ma application ;
the app alarm should not ring when ma phone is in silent mode. how this can be done?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/), and [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Use the getRingerMode() method in AudioManager.
`AudioManager am = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

switch (am.getRingerMode()) {
    case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT:
        Log.i("MyApp","Silent mode");
        break;
    case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE:
        Log.i("MyApp","Vibrate mode");
        break;
    case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL:
        Log.i("MyApp","Normal mode");
        break;
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

Try figuring out how to determine the volume settings of the phone at that current moment before you tell the notification/alarm to ring.

Comment: Will anyone explain me briefly .